# Graphics problems: no screen and can't enter GRUB

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, graphics

I am setting up my new PC with an MSI GeForce GTX 1660 graphics card. Graphics doesn't work and I am deep into debugging and trying to install Ubuntu 19.10.

What i can do is:

- Enter and see BIOS
- Enter the live USB install menu
- From that menu, I can use the "Try Ubuntu (safe graphics)" and "Install Ubuntu (safe graphics)" options. Through this, I can actually install Ubuntu.
- After installing, I can get into the GRUB menu **just once** through the BIOS (I **can't** get there by holding `SHIFT` (which is a big problem).
- From the boot menu, I can set the `nomodeset` kernel option by presseing `e`, which takes like 5 minutes as of [this problem described here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1227735/236004).
- But then, I can actually boot - **once**.

What I can't:

- The normal install mode -> purple screen, with some disrupted lines at the top of the screen
- Hold the GRUB menu with the shift key -> possibly due to the 1 seconds slowliness?
- Boot Ubuntu (installed with safe graphics) -> distorted video as above
- Once I entered Ubuntu (through the `nomodeset` trick above), I can't get into the GRUB menu again, e.g. to set `nomodeset` again. Before, I could go there through BIOS, where I can select which boot menu to enter. After I entered Ubuntu once, I can't reach that menu anymore. It will always try to boot and will always see the empty/distorted screen.

So the only way for me to try something new is **to install Ubuntu again**. And actually I can't try much new then, because I have erased my system. The cycle time for that is around 30 minutes per attempt.

So I am desperately looking for a way **how to enter the boot menu**. `Shift` just doesn't work.

Comment: After you boot with the black screen, can you get to a TTY by pressing CTRL+ALT+F3 or CTRL+ALT+F4? This should take you to a TTY screen where you can log in with your username and password. From there, try running: `sudo apt update; sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` It's probably best if you are connected through ethernet as wifi probably isn't set up. If you do have network problems, post back a comment as there are a few commands you can use to get that started via command line.

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your tip! Unfortunately, I can't try your tip anymore, as I could solve the problem by now - and don't want to go back to that miserable situation I was in :D. It turned out that I *could* get into the Grub menu after all, when I pressed `ESC` at the right time. If I pressed it twice at the wrong time, I would enter Grub but enter the grub terminal.
Eventually, I needed only 2 more attempts to install the Nvidia driver.

Comment: Far out my console jumped to either `F7` or `F8` ... wth... thanks @mchid I wasn't expecting it to jump over there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess my question and seek for help can be answered as:
It **is indeed** possible to get into the Grub menu, when I pressed `ESC` at the right time. I could figure out the right time by repeatedly pressing `ESC` - but by that it would enter the menu, but then exit it right away into the `> grub` terminal, where I didn't want to be due to the massive slowliness of things.

So I had to find the moment where I could press `ESC` once, and from there I could move on.

Unfortunately, I didn't get the chance to try and confirm what @mchid suggested. Sorry for that, but thanks a lot for trying to help!