# No video/display in logon screen after user logoff (4k display, nvidia)

Tags: nvidia, 19.10, login-screen, logout, 4k-monitor

When I logoff the user and expecting to see the **logon screen** (unity-greeter), my monitor looses the signal and stays black (repeatedly trying someting, but failing).
I can get a terminal with `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, and after `Alt+F7` I have infact my logon screen.

When I was setting up my system, I was facing severe problems with my graphics adapter (*NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1660*) and the 4k display (3840x2160), due to which I didn't get video signal in Ubuntu installation (see also [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1227748/236004)).

Also in the **lock screen** (`special+L`) I lost video. This I could already fix by [this suggestion](https://askubuntu.com/a/700163/236004), but to be honest I didn't know what I was doing there.

Is my NVIDIA driver still not configured correctly?

```
$ lsb_release -a  
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

Here is some output ([motivated from here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-check-nvidia-driver-version-on-your-linux-system):

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Sat Apr 18 13:30:20 2020       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Graphics Device     Off  | 00000000:08:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 42%   34C    P0    34W / 125W |    507MiB /  5910MiB |      1%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0     13069      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           242MiB |
|    0     13495      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         259MiB |
|    0     15469      G   gnome-control-center                           3MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

```
$ grep "X Driver" /var/log/Xorg.0.log
[   794.441] (II) NVIDIA dlloader X Driver  435.21  Sun Aug 25 08:17:08 CDT 2019
```

**Is my driver in the right location?**

```
$ modinfo /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko | grep ^version 
modinfo: ERROR: Module /usr/lib/modules/5.3.0-46-generic/kernel/drivers/video/nvidia.ko not found.

$ find /usr/lib/modules -name nvidia.ko
/usr/lib/modules/5.3.0-46-generic/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko

$ modinfo /usr/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates/dkms/nvidia.ko | grep ^version
version:        435.21
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out, when I use a DisplayPort cable instead of the HDMI cable, I do have a display in the logon/logout screen with no problem. Before, I didn't have a DP cable, so I was using HDMI.

This is a solution for me, and hopefully for others it can be too. Although it doesn't actually solve the technical problem.